# Electric panel heater to smart

Tags: electric-machine, appliances, smart

I just bought a house that comes with [these panels for heating](https://www.rinnai.com.au/online/heating/electric-panel-heaters/rinnai-peph-series/1500w-electric-panel-heater-copy/).

The panel has a timer but I’d like to explore if there is any smart option. The option I initially checked is those smart WiFi plug, but the panel loses all its settings once is switched off from the main power and not from its power button.

Is there any way to make the panel smart?

Comment: _”However, the panel looses all its settings once is switched off from the main power and not from its power button.”_ Unacceptably bad in 2022.

Answer (score 3):

From the sound of it you can't do anything without opening it up and replacing the built in timer with you own "home brew" smart controller, or bypassing the timer so that the heating elements are connected directly to the mains input and thence to the smart plug. Unless you are a competent electrical engineer I would strongly advise against either course of action.

In addition it looks as if you live in Australia (from the web site you reference) and I believe oz has very strict rules on who can do what to mains powered equipment and house wiring. So any of the above suggestions would probably be illegal in your country, and would be looked on as dangerous by your insurers.

Your only safe solution is to get the panels replaced by new, smart ones.

Comment: Thank you Peter, it’s pretty clear i shouldn’t do anything

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Bypass the smarts in the heater and use your Wi-Fi plug.

Take care not to bypass any safety thermal protection devices such as a safety stat. There are fire insurance implications to doing this work.

Comment: Thanks! could  you pls provide some more details or link on some basics? I’m not really sure what do you mean to bypass the heater’s smarts..

Comment: Then, I'm afraid, you're not qualified to take on the project. Sorry. Mains power and heat sources aren't the best place to start learning.

Comment: Thanks Transistor for your time. I’ll just go with the timers.